# Generate new polygons from a cut polygon (2D)

Tags: algorithm, polygon, intersection, computational-geometry

I'm stuck with this little problem and my algorithm to solve this doesn't hold for all cases. Does anybody has an idea how to solve this?

**Here's an example polygon:**

[example http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/8804/poly.png](http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/8804/poly.png)

**Formal description**

We have a list of points in CW order defining the polygon. We also can query whether a point is a cutting point with `is_cut(p)`, where `p` is a given point. Now we want to compute new polygons caused by this "cut".

**The algorithm should do this:**

Input: `{a, c1, b, c4, c, c5, d, c6, e, c3, f, c2}`

Output: `{a, c1, c2}`, `{b, c4, c3, f, c2, c1}`, `{d, c6, c5}`, `{e, c3, c4,  c, c5, c6}`

**Here my current algorithm:**

```
follow your points, CW
if the point is a cut point
-> go back trough the list looking for cut points
--- if next cut point is connected to the current cut point 
    and not part of the current poly, follow it
--- else keep searching
else
-> continue until you hit your starting point.
that's a poly
do this for every non-cut-point
```

This algorithm doesn't hold if you'd start at `c` or `f`.

Comment: When I saw your picture I finally understood the output. However I don't think, given this input, the computer can somehow magically guess that the C coordinates all belong together. So I would think that apart form the coordinates of the polygon, you also need a separe input array specifying which of these indices are the indices to cut by.    More logical would be: one polygon, and 1 vector which defines the cutting line

Comment: Correct, I computed the c_n points before, hence I can provide a function is_cut(p), which would form such a list {c1,...,cn}, where n mod 2 == 0.

I'm sorry about the picture, but stackoverflow doesn't allow me yet to post pictures :(.

Comment: I added also a pseudocode algorithm, which I used for know.

Comment: hm... that picture reminds me something I see every day in the underground. (pic) http://alloyfirms.ru/bank/5295_moscow.gif

Comment: @pavel: This is my underground map http://www.ecampmany.com/NY/Subwaymap.gif

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should calculate what segments of the cutting line belong to internals of your original polygon.  That's a classical problem, and its solution is simple. Given that your points `c1, c2, c3 ... c6` are laid out along the line in exactly this order, then segments `c1-c2`, `c3-c4` etc will always belong to polygon internals (*).

Now we can construct simple recursive algorithm for cutting polygons.  Given your big input array, {a, c1, b, c4, c, c5, d, c6, e, c3, f, c2}, start from any polygon point, for example, `b`; add it to array *`result`*.  Traverse the input array forward.  If you encounter

- **usual polygon node**, push it to array *`result`*.
- **`ck` node, where `k` is odd**, look for `c(k+1)` and keep traversing from its position.
- **`ck` node, where `k` is even**, look for `c(k-1)`, jump to its position and keep nevertheless traversing forward.

For last two cases, add these nodes in the order you encountered them to *`result`* array.  Add `ck` node to set *`cut`*, and add another node (`c(k+1)` or `c(k-1)`, whichever you've got) into a global set *`done`*.

If you'll have to go beyond the last element, circuit to the first element in the input array.

Sooner or later you'll encounter the initial node you were traversing from.  Now in the *`result`* array you have a polygon you've cut.  Remember it.  Repeat the procedure recursively, starting from position of each node that belongs to *`cut`* set and doesn't belong to the global *`done`* set.

That's the solution as I see it.  But it's computational geomentry, so it may turn a bit more complex than it seems.

---

For our example, start from `b`:

1. *`done={}`*, start from `b`.  After first pass, you'll get *`result=[b,c4,c3,f,c2,c1]`*, *`cut={c4,c2}`*, *`done={c3,c1}`*;  Recurse to `c4` and `c2` nodes.
2. *`done={c3;c1}`*, start from `c4` (recursion from 1).  After this pass, you'll get *`result=[c4,c,c5,c6,e,c3,c4]`*, *`cut={c5,c3}`*, *`done+={c6,c4}`*;  Recurse to `c5`.
3. *`done={c3;c1;c4;c6}`*, start from `c2` (recursion from 1).  After this pass, you'll get *`result=[c2,a,c1]`*, *`cut={c1}`*, *`done+={c2}`*;  Don't recurse to `c1`, since it's in *`done`* set;
4. *`done={c3;c1;c4;c6;c2}`*, start from `c5` (recursion from 2).  After this pass, you'll get *`result=[c5,d,c6]`*, *`cut={c5}`*, *`done+={c6}`*;  Don't recurse to `c5`, since it's in *`done`* set;

Voila - you get 4 polygons you've needed.

---

(*) Note that it requires more "mathematical" representation of the line.  For example, if one of the polygon vertexes is on the line, the vertex should be doubled, i.e. if `c` point was a bit closer to the right side and on the red line, the line would have `[c1, c2, c3, c, c, c6]` points on it, and the polygon array would be `[a, c1, b, c, c, c, d, c6, e, c3, f, c2]`.

Sometimes (not in this example), it may lead to cutting "empty" polygons, such as `[a, a, a]`.  If you don't need them, you can eliminate them at late stages.  Anyway, it's computational geometry with an immense number of border cases.  I can't include them all in one answer...

Comment: Quote: *...segments c1-c2, c3-c4 etc will always belong to polygon internals...*, will not always hold. For example, remove the cutting-points `c4` and `c5` and let `c` be the cutting point instead.

Comment: @Bart K., there's no mistake in it.  Added explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply you were wrong. It's just that you make it sound real easy, while there are (as you yourself mention) quite a bit of tricky corner cases one needs to account for.

Comment: Stunning answer! Great that you stepped though it after you explained what to do.

Answer (score 3):

You could apply [Weiler Atherton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler-Atherton_clipping_algorithm) clipping (effectively what Pavel is suggesting), but there is a huge caveat.

Due to floating point errors, the W/A clipping algorithm is extremely difficult to get working well - In cases such as the clipping line passing through a vertex, or precisely along an edge of the polygon, the algorithm can become confused about which "path" around the perimiter of the polygon it should follow and it then outputs incorrect results.

Comment: What I suggest can be easily extended to handling such cases, but my algorithm doesn't need to know anything about floating-point arithmetic, it just traverses the arrays given (which also don't require much of precision).

Comment: Which is right: "it's computational geometry with an immense number of border cases"  or "[it] can be easily extended to handling such cases"? Anyone who has attempted to implement these methods can tell you that the algorithm above takes only a few minutes to implement, and a great deal longer to actually get working in a generalised and useful sense. If you make a single wrong decision (easily done as everyone knows "computers can't do maths") when traversing your node hierarchy, you will generate incorrect outputs.

Answer (score 0):

**1 find side each point is**

pick one pont that is not on cut (a for instance) and set that it is on left side (it does not metter actaly)

when you go over points on cut, side of point you reach  change. So you find left/right points.

Problem is that you should also consider that order of points should be in predifined way. (clockwise for instance)

**2 start at each midsection of cx and go once clockwise and counterclockwise.**

For each polygon you hit midsection in one direction only once.

If you "overflow" c that mean that you reach outer polynom.
You might solve this problem if you define c0 and cmax which lies on polgon and you have than

```
input =  {a, c1, c0 ,c1, b, c4, c, c5, d, c6, c7, c6, e, c3, f, c2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest to implement is [Sutherland-Hodgman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_clipping_algorithm). The one problem with it is that it leaves little zero area slivers connecting the polys  on one side of the line. In your example, this would give you something like :

> {a c2 c3 e c6 c5 c c4 c1} and {b c1 c2 f c3 c6 d c5 c4}

If you could live with this or figure out how to break them up into the pieces you want, then you would find that the code which did the actual clipping would be about as simple as possible.

The implementation simply requires two stacks and a single pass through the vertices of your polygon. At each vertex you check to see if you've crossed the line since the previous vertex. If so, compute the crossing point and push it on one of the stacks. Then push the new vertex onto one of the stacks. Really easy.