# Cut Polygon Function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there an existing matlab implementation of cut polygon function? Such as the one that is based on [Generate new polygons from a cut polygon (2D)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775457/generate-new-polygons-from-a-cut-polygon-2d)?

I understand that we have [this implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24449), but looking at the source code, I don't think this is a correct implementation ( just my hunch) because it distinguishes vertical and horizontal lines in the checking ( A good algorithm should just don't care about whether the line is vertical or not, for the concept of vertical/horizontal is arbitrary).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an intrinsic function. Have you looked at the algorithm here?

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/49192

You should be able to track down the original paper to confirm validity.